# How to import a schema sql file using pgadmin 4?

Tags: sql, import, pgadmin-4

Is it possible? If so how?

I can only find solution for pgadmin 3 which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 34):

It worked like this for me:

1. Go to your Database and click on this.
2. Click in the menubar on `Tools`, `Query Tools`

[image]

3. Then it reload the page. Above the menubar on the left, you see the *folder*-icon (*look picture below*). Click on them and choose your `.sql` file
4. Click on `select` and the file is uploaded
5. To execute the `.sql` file, press F5 or the play button above the menubar in the middle (*look at the screenshot below*).
6. Right click on your database and click on 'Refresh'.

[image]

Comment: I'm importing the sql file  like as the answer mentioned above  but it says  `File type not supported`. my file is like `test.sql`.

Answer (score 10):

Following are the step that will help you in importing all tables of your schema

1) Open pgAdmin 4

2) Navigate to Your Database Name --> Schemas --> public

3) Then right click on public

4) After clicking on public then select Restore option from DropDown Menu

5) A window will open in which you only have to give location of .sql file and leave other textboxes

6) Click Restore and leave rest on pgadmin

**Note** **:**
You have to perform these steps for every single table you want to import

Comment: if it did not work try using pgsql Shell 
enter your server and database and user information then run without any quotes

    \i D:/folder/your_table.sql

Comment: In my case, DB already had data, and restore failed. To resolve it I dropped DB and created a new one assigning the same user which is used for backup. Then the answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To handle this problem, follow these steps:

1. Select your Database.
2. Click in the menubar, select Tools & Query Tools,
3. Import your SQL (to generate query create table)
4. Execute query